# how to make a CRC in python for a serial device?

Tags: java, python, pyserial, crc

I have to build a serial comunication app using python, the old app is only working on windows xp and was written in C. Now i have to switch to linux and i dont have a working driver. I started to code it myself. I got the protocol from the producing company of the serial device.
   The serial device receives and sends data wich is ended by a CRC. I'm new to python and i dont have a solution for this, maybe someone can help me.

This is the CRC alghoritm:

```
  ALGORITHM FOR CRC CALCULATION

The two CRC bytes are calculated according to the formula x^15 + 1. In the calculation are included all data bytes plus the byte for block end. Every byte passes through the calculation register from teh MSB to LSB.
Three working bytes are used - S1, S0 and TR
S1 - Most significant byte from the CRC ( it is transmitted immediatelly after END)
S0 - Least significant byte from the CRC ( It is transmitted after S1)
TR - the current transmitted byte in the block.

The CRC is calculated as follows:
1. S1 and S0 are zeroed
2. TR is loaded with the current transmitted byte. The byte is transmitted.
3. Points 3.1 and 3.2 are executed 8 times:
3.1. S1, S0 and TR are shifted one bit to the left.
3.2. If the carry bit from S1 is 1, the MSB of S1 and LSB of S0 are inverted.
Points 2 and 3 are executed for all bytes, included in the calculation of the CRC - from the first byte after BEG up to and including byte END.
4. TR is loaded with 0 and point 3 is executed
5. TR is loaded with 0 and point 3 is executed
6. Byte S1 is transmitted
7. Byte S0 is transmitted

ALGORITHM FOR CRC CHECK ON RECEIVING

Three working bytes are used S1, S0 and RC

S1 - Most significant byte from the CRC ( it is received immediately after END)
S0 - Least significant byte from the CRC ( transmitted after S1)
RC - the current received byte in the block ( beginning from the first byte after BEG and ending 2 bytes after END).

The CRC is obtained as follows:
1. S1 and S0 are zeroed
2. RC is loaded with the current received byte
3. Points 3.1 and 3.2 are executed 8 times:
3.1. S1, S0 and RC are shifted 8 times to the left
3.2. if the MSB of S1 is 1 then MSB of S1 and LSB of S0 are inverted. 
Points 2 and 3 are executed for all bytes, included in the calculation of the CRC - from the first byte after BEG up to and including 2 bytes after END.
S1 and S0 must be 0.
```

If there is someone wich can show me how to do it i'll be very gratefull.Thank you all.

**EDIT 1:**

I managed to get the same CRC procedure made by someone, but its made in java, i'm not that good with java. Maybe you can guide me into converting it in python. This is the code:

```
public class Crc {
    public static final String CRC_NAME = "CRC-16-ECR";
    private static final int POLYNOMIAL = 32769;
    public static final int WIDTH = 16;
    public static final int TOPBIT = 32768;
    short CRC;
    short[] crcTable = new short[256];

    public Crc() {
        this.crcInit();
    }

    private void crcInit() {
        for(int dividend = 0; dividend < 256; ++dividend) {
            int remainder = dividend << 8;

            for(byte bit = 8; bit > 0; --bit) {
                if((remainder & '耀') != 0) {
                    remainder = (remainder << 1 ^ '老') & '\uffff';
                } else {
                    remainder = remainder << 1 & '\uffff';
                }
            }

            this.crcTable[dividend] = (short)remainder;
        }

    }

    public short crcFast(byte[] message, int nBytes) {
        int remainder = 0;

        for(int oneByte = 0; oneByte < nBytes; ++oneByte) {
            int data = (message[oneByte] ^ remainder >> 8) & 255;
            remainder = this.crcTable[data] ^ remainder << 8;
        }

        return (short)remainder;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but only advices. If you have access to the C code read it. It is often simpler to translate from one language to another one than to write from scratch. And it can be used also to build a test program in C to control how the legacy application computed the CRC of a message, and compare to the new Python code. If you cannot, first translate the algo in pseudo code and compute *by hand* the CRC of one simple message, and then write it in Python and control that the result is what you expected.

Comment: i have de C files but not the sources. do you think i can implement the dll files in python and make it work under linux?

Comment: @BogdanRadu If you don't have the source, you don't have the C files.

Comment: Ok, I rectify . I have DLL files and one .so file.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
crc = 0
while True:
    ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
    if not ch:
        break
    crc ^= ord(ch) << 8
    for _ in range(8):
        crc = crc << 1 if (crc & 0x8000) == 0 else (crc << 1) ^ 0x8001
    crc &= 0xffff
print(format(crc, '04x'))
```

Comment: hi, is this python2? or python3?  i get this error `print format(crc, '04x') SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. i'll better check on both

Comment: ok, i solved the error, can i contact you on a private channel? so we can discuss directly. i would like you to explain me some of your code, i'm new and i would like to learn.  thank you

Comment: No, just ask new questions on this site. (Though not in the comments here.)

Comment: ok, can you explain to me what this is `0x8000` ? it was extrated from line `crc = crc << 1 if (crc & 0x8000) == 0 else (crc << 1) ^ 0x8001`

Comment: The comments are not for more questions.